# I need to find a line of text in python and copy it, and the lines above and below it

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Basically, I need to find a line of text in python (and tk) and copy it, and the lines above and below it.

```
Imported_File = a long list of strings. 
One_Ring = the line I'm looking for.
```

> Find One_ring in Imported_File, Copy One_ring, the line above it and below it to Output_Var

I'm really stuck, any help would be amazing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are looking the exact line

```
imported_file = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

one_ring = 'd'

if one_ring in imported_file:
    i = imported_file.index(one_ring)

    start = i-1
    end = i+2

    # problem with first element before "a" when `one_ring = 'a'`
    if start < 0: 
        start = 0

    output_var = imported_file[start:end]

    print(output_var)

 else:
    print('not found')
```

---

**BTW:** use `lower_case` names for varaibles: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)

Comment: Thank you so much! This had been a problem for ages and it's working now!

Comment: I wish you fantastic Code Kalma! Thanks my friend!

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are reading from a file which has these long list of strings.

```
with open('textFile.txt') as f:
  Imported_File = f.readlines()
  One_Ring = "This is the line\n"
  Output_Var = ""

  if One_Ring in Imported_File:
    idx = Imported_File.index(One_Ring)
    Output_Var = Imported_File[max(0, idx - 1):idx+2]

  print(Output_Var)
```

The textFile.txt would be your input file. I created a sample file which looks like

```
Hello there
How are you
This is the line
Done, Bye
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! You're a star!

Comment: you may get wrong result if you look for `"Hello there"` because `idx` is `0` and `idx-1` gives you `-1` so you get last element from list and you get result: `"Done, Bye Hello there How are you"`. You will have problem when you look for `"Done, Bye"` because `[idx+1]` gives you error `"IndexError: list index out of range"`

Comment: Obviously I wasn't checking the corner cases. Just wanted the OP to get going. Better post a correct answer than a partially correct one. Thanks for pointing out.